# cheer up / buck up / perk up /. Which makes more sense in the given context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquial-language, word-in-context

> Not only did I not get tired, I rather cheered up/perked up/bucked up.
>
> Not only did I not tire, rather I was/felt invigorated.

Do any of these seem natural to you?

Comment: The "cheer" version doesn't really make sense ("to cheer up" means to stop being sad, which is nothing to do with being tired). Personally, I think that after a construction of the general form ***Not only** NOT(X)*, it's stylistically "clumsy" to explicitly include the word ***rather*** before the following "contrastive" assertion (which is invariably something that's *the complete opposite of X*, or otherwise clearly incompatible with X). Consider *Not only did did he not help, he [actually] made things worse* (intensifier ***actually*** is good there, but ***rather*** isn't really good).

Comment: Not only did I not tire, I [actually] felt/was [actually] invigorated/refreshed. Right?

Comment: Yes, either of those are syntactically fine. Stylistically, it's better if the negated / denied action (tiring, becoming tired) and the actual action (perking up, becoming refreshed) are expressed using "compatible" verb forms. As in *Not only did I not tire, I actually strengthened*. But those single-word verbs are both a bit "formal, starchy" for the context, so multi-word "transitional" verb forms might be preferred: *Not only did I not **get tired**, I actually **got stronger*** (where the "parallelism" of ***get X*** constructions is particularly natural and idiomatic).

Comment: "Not only did I not get tired, but I [also\actually\in fact] got invigorated/refreshed". What about this one?

Comment: As previously implied, ***but*** (same as ***rather***) is at the very least "redundant" in such contexts. But personally I'd would advise you to forget about starting your sentence with ***not only*** in the first place. It's more trouble than it's worth to figure out which alternative (to the common-as-muck construction ***not only ... but also***) will work. Just *I didn't get tired - I [actually] got stronger* will always sound good, and that's just one thing to learn. You could learn a dozen alternatives that are *also* okay, but it would be hard to learn all those that *don't* work.

Comment: You normally cheer up, perk up or buck up _after_ feeling glum or tired, not _instead of_.

Comment: @KateBunting - they all imply an 'uplift' but from different prior states. Going from sad to perky doesn't really work, but going from 'thinking you might get tired' to 'feeling remarkably energetic' feels right to me.

Answer (score 3):

*I felt invigorated* might fit, or, less formally, *I felt refreshed*.
Those seem like good antonyms to *tired*.

Comment: "Not only did I tire/get tired, I rather felt invigorated/refreshed" Does  any of these combinations look good?

Comment: @Rusletov: You're confusing the issue by randomly switching between following ***not only*** with a "positive" clause (did I tire) and the "negated" version in the question (did I **not** tire).

Comment: @Rusletov You've left out the negation. *Not only did I **not** get tired, I felt refreshed.*  As FumbleFingers's comment above says, the word *rather* isn't needed.

Comment: Sorry, just didn't notice while typing. Of course I meant "Not only did I NOT tire/get tired, I rather felt invigorated/refreshed"

Answer (score 2):

If you were forced to choose from the first three alternatives, here's perhaps how you'd make your decision…

> Not only did I not get tired, I rather cheered up/perked up/bucked up.

1. Cheered up -
   you were sad, but are now becoming happier.
2. Perked up -
   'perky' is lively, invigorated, at full attention, 'bright-eyed and bushy-tailed'. It may include cheerfulness, but that's not necessary to the meaning.
3. Bucked up - *This one I find the hardest to explain concisely and clearly.*
   If you are performing poorly, or even showing extreme anxiety or sadness, someone may [rather unkindly, no matter how well-meant] tell you to 'buck up your ideas' or 'pull yourself together'. In that way, it's rather an admonishment of your current performance or mind-set. You can do this to yourself without external advice or compulsion, but it would still imply that your previous mental or physical state was lower & in need of an attitude change to compensate.

This would leave 'perked up' as possibly the most appropriate in this situation.